# bouncing ball as audio media-overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to make a ball bounce on each word with audio. Is it missing in all tutorials of media-overlay or am i missing that ?

To make MediaOverlay, all tutorial say that we should:

1. in xhtml witch contain the text;

   ## Chapter 1. Loomings.

   Call me Ishmael. 
   Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world.
2. associated .smil file;

   `<seq id="id1" epub:textref="chapter_001.xhtml" epub:type="bodymatter chapter">
   <par id="sentence0"><text src="chapter_001.xhtml#c001s0000"/><audio src="audio/mobydick_001_002_melville.mp4" clipBegin="0:00:21" clipEnd="0:00:28"/></par>
   <par id="sentence1"><text src="chapter_001.xhtml#c001s0001"/><audio src="audio/mobydick_001_002_melville.mp4" clipBegin="0:00:28" clipEnd="0:00:30"/></par>
   <par id="sentence2"><text src="chapter_001.xhtml#c001s0002"/><audio src="audio/mobydick_001_002_melville.mp4" clipBegin="0:00:30" clipEnd="0:00:44"/></par>`
3. the audio(.mp4) is saved where it should be.

   (audio/mobydick_001_002_melville.mp4)
4. association between .xhtml and .smil is done in opf file:

   ```
   <item id="xchapter_001" href="chapter_001.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" media-overlay="chapter_001_overlay"/>
   ```
5. and in css mentioned:

   .-epub-media-overlay-active {
   color: #dc4c37;
   }
6. My question is, can we make a bouncing ball media-overlay for each word instead of Highlighting the text.